# 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk

I upgraded my SDK version from 1.14.5 (dev channel) to 2.0.1 (stable channel). When i do that i started to get this error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: run pub get and then pub upgrade

Comment: And after that flutter clean

Comment: i tried these steps just now and still same